# NSString in DrawRect text alignment

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am using the DrawRect method to draw some text and can't figure out how to align this text to the right.

I know in interface builder you can specify the alignment so I know it is possible, I just can't seem to figure it out my self.

Any help at this point is extremely helpful.

Thanks so much!

```
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-UltraLight" size:12], NSFontAttributeName, [NSColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    NSAttributedString * newEmail = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newUnreadEmail] attributes:attributes];
    [newEmail drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(140, 600)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do math to calculate the correct point for the right alignment. Use `[newEmail size]` to calculate the width of the attributed string, subtract it from the width of the rectangle in which you would like it painted, and add the difference to the left coordinate of the point that you pass to the `drawAtPoint:` method.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I do have one question: How do I store the `[newEmail size]` in an integer to do the math on? Thanks again!

Comment: @jtorraca `size` returns `NSSize` struct, which contains dimensions in both coordinates. You can use `CGFloat w = [newEmail size].width;` to get the width of the text. You could use `int` instead of `CGFloat`, but `CGFloat` gives you better precision in case the width  has a fraction.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using an `NSString` class, your life would be easier because you could use the `UIStringDrawing` extension of `NSString` class with the following methods (you don't need to do any extra thing to use these methods with the `NSString`):

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font;
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size;
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

they give you the exact size of the current string for the selected `UIFont` and `UILineBreakMode`, and using the size you can count the position on the screen to align the right edge of the string always at the same position.